# How do I make a 'when' string case insensitive?

Tags: ruby

If a user writes *Why* instead of *why*, the bot won't answer. How do I make these command case insensitive?

```
when /why/ 
    bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Because")
```

Comment: Add an `i` flag: `/why/i`

Comment: use regex flag `when /why/i` (for "case Insensitive")

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Comment: Use [`/why/i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options) option/modifier to make a match case-insensitive (sorry, I could not resist the necessity to post the most descriptive comment here.)

Comment: Note that `/why/` will also match strings _containing_ `why` so you might have to add anchors. Another common approach is to downcase the input and compare it to lowercase strings, i.e. `case input.downcase` and `when 'why'`.

Comment: If this is a high-throughput application and you are matching on exact strings but in a case-insensitive way, I'd recommend using `casecmp?` which is faster than a regex. `"WhY".casecmp?("why") => true`

Answer (score 5):

You can add an `i` [option](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options) to make the regexp case insensitive:

```
case input
when /why/i
  # ...
end
```

Since this would also match strings *containing* `why`, you might want to add [anchors](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) for beginning of line `^` and end of line `$`: (assuming your input is a single line)

```
case input
when /^why$/i
  # ...
end
```

For multi-line strings, there's `\A` and `\z` .

Another common approach is to [`downcase`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-downcase) the input and compare it to lowercase strings (not regexes):

```
case input.downcase
when 'why'
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Do we know that the string contains a single word? If not, anchors are not the answer.